# Build either trial or commercial binary and change runtime behavior accordingly

Tags: go

## Build

I have this `Makefile` to build a binary for *trial* and *commercial* use:

```
BINARY_NAME=App.exe
 
trial:
    ENV_BUILD=trial go build -o ${BINARY_NAME}

comme:
    ENV_BUILD=comme go build -o ${BINARY_NAME}

clean:
    go clean
    rm ${BINARY_NAME}

prepare:
    go mod tidy
```

## Source code

Inside my source code, I have a source code that asserts the *trial* and *commercial* limitations:

```golang
package permit

import "fmt"

func Trial() (bool, error) {
    fmt.Println("You are using a limited trial release.")
    // ...
    // Assert limitations...
}

func Comme() (bool, error) {
    fmt.Println("You are using the unlimited commercial release.")
    // ...
}
```

I plan to call the above two functions at runtime like this:

```golang
package main

import "permit"

    // ...

    var builtTrial bool // TODO: Best way to detect if the built has been trial
    var builtComme bool // TODO: Best way to detect if the built has been commercial

    if builtTrial {
        permitted, err := permit.Trial()
    } else if builtComme {
        permitted, err := permit.Comme()
    }

    // ...
```

## Question

What's the best practice to detect at runtime that the binary is built as *trial* or *commercial*? I feel like I don't know the available standard tools to do so.

Comment: go mod tidy is misplaced. Never call go build with filename arguments (unless you know what you are doing).

Comment: @Volker Thanks. I tested `go build` without a filename argument. It worked. I edited my posts here.

Comment: @Volker I don't understand when you mentioned that `go mod tidy` is misplaced. What does it mean, can you explain more?

Comment: You do not run go mod tidy as part of your build.

Comment: @Volker Alright. I tried to consider that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually, I went ahead with the Go build tags approach:

File `permit\build_trial.go`:

```golang
//go:build trial

package permit

var buildType = "trial"
```

File `permit\build_commercial.go`:

```golang
//go:build commercial

package permit

var buildType = "commercial"
```

Then, I can have statements like these:

```golang
package permit

// ...

    if buildType == "trial" {
        fmt.Println("You are using a limited trial release.")
        return nil
    } else if buildType == "commercial" {
        fmt.Println("You are using the unlimited commercial release.")
        return nil
    } else {
        return fmt.Errorf("build type is neither trial nor commercial.")
    }
```

The final `Makefile` is:

```
BINARY_NAME=App.exe
 
trial:
    go build -tags trial -o ${BINARY_NAME}

commercial:
    go build -tags commercial -o ${BINARY_NAME}

clean:
    go clean
    rm ${BINARY_NAME}

prepare:
    go mod tidy
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `ldflags` option, to change a variable on build time ( link time?! ). Available options are presented [here](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/link) and I'm going to use the `-X` option to change your variable:

```
package main

import "permit"

var BuildType = "trial"

func main() {
    // ...

    if BuildType == "trial" {
        permitted, err := permit.Trial()
    } else if BuildType == "commercial" {
        permitted, err := permit.Comme()
    }

    // ...
}
```

now you can set the `BuildType` variable on build time like this:

```
go build -ldflags="-X 'main.BuildType=commercial'"
```

Comment: I'm searching and I see things like build tags or build constraints in Go. Statements like `// +build trial` or `// +build commercial` above the Go source files. Maybe that's another option. I'm not sure.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/customizing-go-binaries-with-build-tags